# Rails return to calling function inside if else block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, recursion

I am using a recursive function.

```
def abc
   get_course_to_be_deleted( courses, array_course_name, nil )
end

def self.get_course_to_be_deleted( courses, array_course_name, course )
   if array_course_name.blank?
    #### array_course_name = []
   course
  else
     #### array_course_name = ['Science', 'Maths']
     array_course_name.each do |course_name|
     course = courses.detect{ |course| course.name == course_name  }
     course_names = array_course_name - [ course_name ]
     get_course_to_be_deleted( course.children, course_names, course )
  end
 end
```

end

Tried .empty? its not working! array_course_name is always an array, assume a case i have three courses in array_course_names say [ 'Science', 'Botany', 'Zoology'].    For the first time the course object will be Science object, course_names  would  be ['Botany', 'Zoology'], course.children would be botany object. as same it continues to execute the loop.At the last cycle array_course_names would be blank, course would be Zoology object, in that case i would like to return the found zoology object to calling function, but it is **NOT** getting returned to calling function instead it goes to else block with array_course_names as ['Botany', 'Zoology'] and which throws an error 'undefined method children for nil class' since there is no course exists.  How to exit from recursive function when a condition is satisfied??

Comment: there's no reason for this not to work, double check your variables and if condition

Comment: I have checked it. It is not returning the course variable instead it enters else part after the last cycle with course_name as [science, maths]

Comment: Add `puts "\n###\n array_course_name: #{array_course_name}; array_course_name.blank? : #{array_course_name.blank?}\n###\n" as the first line in the `self.get_course_to_be_deleted` method, and run the code; the output is likely to show where the logic failure is.

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, where you perform the recursion, you are submitting an Array (formed by the line `course_names = array_course_name - [ course_name ]`) rather than a String.  However, in your test of `if array_course_name.blank?`, you test as though you passed a String.

Either pass a String on the recursion or change your test to see if the Array is empty (or some other similar base case that meets your needs) instead of checking if a String is `blank?`.

This next bit is beyond the likely scope of your OP, but just in case it's an interest of yours:  if you want to support both Arrays and Strings as the type of second parameter, you'll have to add `.class`/`.kind_of?` support for that.

Comment: Have you tried testing `array_course_name.count > 0`?   `.blank?` is certainly wrong, `.empty?` could work.  Without debugging using trace statements it's otherwise hard to tell.  It's not obvious from the code but you might try `.flatten.uniq` on the Array too just to be sure that the value isn't `[[]]` which would seem empty, but of course wouldn't be.

Comment: You could also restructure (at least as a debugging test) and try testing for when `count == 1` and then return the object once you've assigned to `course`.   Logically, that should be functionally neutral to what you're doing  now but still changing it might reveal why it's not working for you as it is.